# Aiff ID3 Tag Info Library for JAVA

Tags: java, tags, aiff

Is there  any library like [TagLib](http://taglib.github.com/) but for Java?

I just want to extract the ID3 Tag info from aiff files.

Comment: Aiff tag library mainly for audio formats.can you specify what is the exact problem? or what is your specific requirement?

Comment: Actually, I just want to extract the ID3 tag info in aiff files. 
By wikipedia [AIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Interchange_File_Format), there is a chunk for ID3 in each aiff file.

Answer (score 0):

The open source library [jaudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) recently added support for tagging aiff with id3 tags

Answer (score -1):

http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/ is written for MP3 files, but it may also work for aiff files (I haven't tried it). It comes with the source files.